# IBM Mobilefirst JAVA adapter: Accessing an JSON file and read contents from it

Tags: java, json, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am using MobileFirstPlatform foundation 7.1. I want to read external JSON file url and read a JSON object from it.

For example I did code for reading image URL, same I have to do for reading JSON file url and read contents from that file. I got code for reading image url from [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/mobileblog/entry/ibm_worklight_adapter_accessing_an_image?lang=en).

Comment: What does the external JSON file url mean? Are you hosting a JSON file in a server? If so, couldn't you use a HTTP adapter to call that URL and get JSON as the return content? What is the issue you face in doing this?

Comment: @VivinK I want to code i that way that I can pass any JSON file URL and I can fetch and return json object from it that's it. File location does not matter whether its on my local pc or any server. My issue is I dont know JAVA in that details so need sample code for this like I shared a link for accessing image url.

Answer (score 0):

To invoke an endpoint from a MFP Java adapter, you need to write the logic that performs this action. You can use Apache HttpClient to invoke your backend - in your case URL where your JSON file is hosted.

Refer to the following tutorials on how to invoke an endpoint from a MFP Java adapter:

1) [Tutorial](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/server-side-development/java-adapter/java-http-adapter/)

2) [Sample Project](https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/JavaAdapters/tree/release71/adapters/RSSAdapter)